# How to add mpeg-4 odsm and sdsm track to a ,mp4

Tags: ffmpeg, video-processing

do anyone has any experiences in adding odsm and sdsm track to a mpeg4 video? I spent hours on ffmpeg and it seems they do not support that.

And after hours of browsing on the Internet, I still could not find any solution on that, may anyone please help, I greatly appreciate that. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [GPAC](https://gpac.wp.imt.fr/):

```
MP4Box -isma somefile.mp4
```

The input file gets replaced with a hinted one.

You can use the same to verify that the tracks where added:

```
MP4Box -std -info somefile.mp4

…
Media Info: Language "Undetermined (und)" - Type "odsm:mp4s" - 1 samples
…
Media Info: Language "Undetermined (und)" - Type "sdsm:mp4s" - 1 samples
…
```